# How to disable spell check popup in Ms Word?

Tags: ms-word

When you click red lined uncorrect text appears a popup that includes some predictions but it's very annoying, how to close it?

[image]

Comment: I think we are stuck with it. Send feedback to MS. https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11 Right-clicking on it will give you something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "helpful" feature continually gets in my way too while editing :/, blocking my view (I use a lot of jargon from computer science). Hopefully someone can later replace my answer with a more official approach via the Word options, but I found today that someone wrote a donationware add-in for it that may help you: (https://wordaddins.com/products/stop-spelling-pop-up-in-word/). Disclaimer: I haven't personally tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Review` > `Language` > `Set Proofing Language` and select `Do not check spelling or grammar` in the popup.

Comment: I want only red line as before :)

Comment: This tells Word to never identify that particular typing as a spelling error. It has nothing to do with the popup.